# I have a seekbar in my preferences to update screen brightness. Is there a way to refresh the UI to see the live change?

Tags: android

The seekbar works fine everywhere, but I'd like to see the changes happen as they are made in that preference screen. The problem is that the seekbar is a preference, and thus I can't do sharedpreferences and update it in the onProgressChanged method.

Is there any way around this?

I set my brightness like this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    float sb = prefs.getInt("screenBrightness", 1);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = sb / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

But I can't use that in onProgressChanged because the class is extending Preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use an `OnSharedPreferencesChanged` listener like `onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)`. Inside of your PreferenceActivity do this:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() { 
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) { 
        if(key.equals("screenBrightness")) {
        //set brightness here
            float sb = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 1);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = sb / 100.0f;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
    }
};
```

and then in `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, you can use the key you've been using and set the brightness accordingly

Comment: I changed my question for clarity. The class onProgressChanged doesn't allow changing the preferences because it is in a preference class.

Comment: @Vee you're using `Preference` or a `PreferenceActivity`? I'm confused..Could you please show the entire class in which the brightness settings are changed?

Comment: Its a preference, in my preference screen. Like this: http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/  

See my edit

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but how do I actually "grab" my seekbar to add a listener to it?

Comment: @Vee see my edit. You can grab any View that is in the parent layout of the activity like this. You use the id and cast it to the type of Widget you know it to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7079/discussion-between-vee-and-luxurymode)