# Live update Screen Brightness with SeekBar

Tags: java, android, seekbar

So I have code that adjusts System Brightness and I have properly implemented the seek bar but when I adjust the seekbar the Screen Brightness does not change. I looked into a few other posts and the solution seems to be to create a Dummy class that opens and closes really quickly. If I do that though then I feel like there would be a ton of lag because the screen would be refreshing constantly as the seekbar is moving.

```
 @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    try{
    int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(cr,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = brightness / 255.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    }
    catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException a)
    {

    }
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started Tracking Seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

Also another problem with the refresh is that I am running this brightness control in a screen where there is a camera preview and killing the camera each time the dummy screen loads would take some time and further increase the lag

I did see this post but I couldnt figure out how to implement it. Since I am not using preferences

[I have a seekbar in my preferences to update screen brightness. Is there a way to refresh the UI to see the live change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023926/i-have-a-seekbar-in-my-preferences-to-update-screen-brightness-is-there-a-way-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code it now works as intended!

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BackLightValue = (float)arg1/100;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

    int SysBackLightValue = (int)(BackLightValue * 255);
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
            SysBackLightValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use my following code it perfectly running :

in your whatever xml file :

```
  <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:max="10"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

note : take attributes as much you need in seekbar.

in your whatever activity use following method and call that :

```
   private void setSeekbar()
   {
       seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setMax(255);
       float curBrightnessValue = 0;

       try {
                curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
                getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
           } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }

    int screen_brightness = (int) curBrightnessValue;
    seekBar.setProgress(screen_brightness);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    int progress = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue,
                boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progresValue;

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                    progress);
        }
    });
  }
```